# C++ less operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm getting this error:

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'const Data' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

But my struct is defined like this:

```
struct Data
{
    String        strData;
    int           intData;
    double        doubleData;

    Data() : intData(-1), doubleData(-0.f)
    {}

    Data(const String& str, int i, double d) : strData(str), intData(i), doubleData(d)
    {}

    const bool operator<(const Data& rightData)
    {
        return strData < rightData.strData;
    }
};
```

I think I have '<' operator, however compiler tells I don't.

One thing to mention, now I'm comparing `const Data` < `Data` types, maybe that `const` makes something bad.

I think it is just a minor mistake, but I just cannot see it...

Comment: `const bool operator<(const Data& rightData)` should be `bool operator<(const Data& rightData) const`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need:

```
bool operator<(const Data& rightData) const
{
    return strData < rightData.strData;
}
```

And also `String` class needs operator as well, if it doesn't have.

Comment: I have `typedef std::string String;` so I think I don't need that.

Comment: Care to add why `const bool` is valid syntax and what it means?

Answer (score 2):

You need a const after the function not before it

```
bool operator<( const Data & rightData ) const
```

Answer (score 0):

`const bool` means the bool returned by the function is constant. 
The error tells you "left-hand operand" should be "of type 'const Data' "
i.e. *a const member function*

So, as the other answers say you need a function which can be called on a `const Data` i.e.

```
bool operator<(const Data& rightData) const
{
    return strData < rightData.strData;
}
```